# Portable Makefiles that call Rscript

Tags: r, makefile, rscript, r-package

I'm writing an R package that generates `Makefile`s, I need to write a `Makefile` that calls `Rscript` before making the targets. A MWE of the problem is below. Make quits in error because the right-hand side of `.INIT` does not execute. Writing a recipe for `file.rds` does not suit my needs.

```
a=1
.INIT=`Rscript -e 'saveRDS('$(a)', "file.rds")'`

all: file2.rds

file2.rds: file.rds
        cp file.rds file2.rds

clean:
        rm file.rds file2.rds
```

What can I do to fix this `Makefile` and keep it portable? From the R extensions manual, I can't use `$(shell` for what I'm trying to accomplish.

---

**EDIT**

From @Spacedman's first answer, I learned that `.INIT` is "expanded"/executed if and only if it is used as a variable somewhere. This is perfect! @Spacedman, I invite you to copy the following `Makefile` into an answer of your own so I can give you credit.

```
a=1
.INIT=`Rscript -e 'saveRDS('$(a)', "file.rds")'`

all: file2.rds

file2.rds:
        echo "file.rds should not have been built."

file3.rds:
        echo -n $(.INIT)
        cp file.rds file3.rds

clean:
        rm file.rds file2.rds
```

The following demonstrates the results I had hoped for.

```
$ make file2.rds
echo "file.rds should not have been built."
file.rds should not have been built.
$ ls file.rds
ls: cannot access file.rds: No such file or directory
$ make file3.rds
echo -n `Rscript -e 'saveRDS('1', "file.rds")'`
cp file.rds file3.rds
$ ls file.rds
file.rds
```

Comment: What error? Do you want the Makefile to create `file.rds` via the .INIT before seeing it as a dependency for file2.rds?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Ridiculous, I know, but the actual use case is different enough to make sense.

Comment: I suspect you are stuffed if you can't use `$(shell` and you can't use a recipe. I don't see another way to run an external command.

Comment: What do you mean by *portable*? Does it need to work with BSD `make`?

Comment: BSD `make`, `dmake`, etc. This is for an [R package](https://github.com/wlandau/parallelRemake), so it needs to follow the [Writing R Extensions guidelines](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Writing-portable-packages).

Comment: Are you planning to put this package on CRAN?

Comment: Yes, once its dependencies are also on CRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `:=` and `$(shell ...)` thus:

```
.INIT := $(shell Rscript -e 'saveRDS('$(a)', "file.rds")')
```

This makes a `simply expanded variable` rather than a `recursively expanded variable`. I think Make doesn't bother even looking at your definition for `.INIT` because its never used.

Backticks don't work like this in Make, you have to use `$(shell ...)`. Can you really not use `$(shell ...)` *anywhere*?

https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html

Test:

```
$ rm file.rds  file2.rds 
$ make
cp file.rds file2.rds
$ ls file*rds
file2.rds  file.rds
```

Which seems to show `make` has created `file.rds` via the R script.

If you *can* put the backquoted string in a recipe, you can make it work (as you discovered!). Note I don't think you need to echo the string, you can just get it expanded and this seems to work:

```
a=1
.INIT=`Rscript -e 'saveRDS('$(a)', "file.rds")'`

all: file2.rds

file2.rds:
    echo "file.rds should not have been built."

file3.rds:
    $(.INIT)
    cp file.rds file3.rds
```

Comment: Yes, I really can't use `$(shell ...)` anywhere.

Comment: See my updated post. You gave me the idea for the solution. Feel free to make the edit into an answer of your own and I will accept it.